# Test coverage tool for cordova custom plugin

Tags: cordova, unit-testing, jasmine, cordova-plugins, test-coverage

I am developing a cordova plugin for both iOS and Android platforms. I googled and got https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-test-framework for writing unit tests. But I could not find any way to do test coverage for my code. Help me out friends.....

Answer (score 2):

I am also doing research on cordova-plugin-test-framework ,
and i have successfully run the test today:)

i have found that , we don't need to configure the plugin.xml file....use cordova-plugin.js and tests.js is enough , just like create a new plugin.

you can get my example from github :

https://github.com/QiuZidane/hello2.git -- android

https://github.com/QiuZidane/hello1.git -- ios

Comment: How does your answer cover the question? OP asked about seeing test coverage, how do YOU manage to do that?